# Adding custom html tags to Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I hover over a custom html tag that I'm using from a platform (Polymer) or even a custom one I made it says that you can mark such a tag as custom somewhere. Is there a place to do this in Intellij? I'm using the latest version (14).

Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated! It would be nice to get rid of all these error highlights when I'm working with Polymer. Thanks!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Place the caret over the highlighted tag, hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and select *Add tag to custom tags*.

However that works only for current project. If you want to set the ignored tags globally, try this:

Go to *Settings/Inspections*, find the *Unknown HTML tag inspection*, select the *Default* profile instead of *Project Default* and specify the tags separated by comma in the textfield in the bottom right corner. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Configuration section]

Comment: what about if we did that accidentally? Is there a way to undo this action? (Already tried CMD+Z)

Comment: @DonkeyKong search for custom html tags > Editor > Inspections select "Unknown Html tag" then in options you can remove the one you added